# Array values clearing after some time automatically

Tags: php, arrays, execution

I am facing a strange issue . I have an array named $ipList which holds a certain number of ip address to pass to a service . Service means an api which executes to check whether ip is in their list or not . This checking is done through a curl session. It executes for one minute, after getting this results , whn i printed my array, it is blank . If i dint execute the call, it will print the array , i think array is cleared after sometime , what to do with this .

```
$ipList=getIpList(); //get iplist
$res=checkService($ipList); //this is the function for checking through curl 
print_r($ipList); // try printing array
```

It prints if i comment the line`$res=checkService($ipList);`

I need help !

Comment: I think you have used `$ipList` variable globally. You have to again check your code.

Comment: Show the code of this function `checkService`

Comment: you are printing `$iplist` which is already defined by you.. and you are commenting `$res`.. if you are going to print `$res` then it will be a blank array

Comment: No this variable is not used as global anywhere. this works fine on some hosting

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that the `checkService` function (your 'API call') is timing out.

Check if that's true. If it is, either try optimizing `checkService` (or the corresponding script) or increase your PHP timeout interval.

**Example :**

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

**Documentation :**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
>   reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
>   seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
>   php.ini.
>
> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero.
>   In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25
>   seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is
>   made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Comment: I have checked, set_time_limit is set to zero . The output of checkService  return the result of operation in an array. It works fine , that is why i doubt, the array is clearing after some time .

Comment: @Kiran Hmm... Would you mind showing us the code of `checkService` too?

Comment: Sorry i cannot show its code, but i guarantee it works fine, not timed out returns results of its operation in array .